# present simple usage

Tags: usage, present-tense

One of the purposes for using present simple is to speak about facts:

E.g. "She lives in London" ... here I know 100% that she lives there, so I use present simple grammar and I add "s" to the verb when I speak
about "he, she, it"

But when I use the word "think" or "maybe", should I still use the present simple grammar, because in this case I am not sure 100% that she lives in London? There is doubt about where she lives.

---

First question:

Should I say "I think she lives in London", or "I think she live in London"?

---

Second question related to the first one:

Is the using of present simple only for telling facts, or can I use it in telling fictional story or imaginary situation?

Comment: We usually refer to [*one of the **reasons** for using](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+the+purposes+for+using%2Cof+the+reasons+for+using&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20the%20purposes%20for%20using%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20the%20reasons%20for%20using%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cof%20the%20purposes%20for%20using%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cof%20the%20reasons%20for%20using%3B%2Cc0) something*, rather than *one of the **purposes** for using it*.

Comment: Welcome on the ELU! Perhaps you think that the usual conventions about writing English do not matter, but they do. I advise you to check your text and use capitals, question marks and other punctuation  where needed, as well as s's that you apparently can place correctly at the end of verbs.  After that people on the ELU wont mind to correct your errors involving real difficulties.

Comment: It makes no difference to the verb form of ***lives*** whether you're making the bald assertion *She lives there* or "qualifying" it as *I think she lives there.* The difference arises if you use an ***auxiliary*** verb to convey your uncertainty, in which case only the auxiliary verb is "tensed", and the "main" verb is in the ***infinitive*** form: ***She might live there***.

Comment: Stories are _usually_ told in the past tense, but it  is possible to tell a story in the present tense to give the reader the feeling of actually being there.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to say it is, "I think she lives in London" or "maybe she lives in London."

More examples:
"I'm not positive, but I think he likes to eat cake."
"I'm not sure, but I think she rides her bike in the morning."